# How to fix "Audio streaming Android app crashing because of service null object reference"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I'am developing the `Audio Streaming Android App`. I used `foreground service` for that. it is working perfectly but in some phone my app crash when stop the `media player`.

I Have check `MediaPlayer Service` is `null` before stop the service. every time it is true in some mobile phones but music is playing in background. so i remove null check. then application automatically close because of above issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayerService.ServiceCallbacks {
    final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ImageButton btnPlay_Puse;
    TextView loadingImage;
    boolean mBounded;
    FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    MediaPlayerService mMediaPlayerService;

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.this;
            mainActivity.mBounded = false;
            mainActivity.mMediaPlayerService = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.this;
            mainActivity.mBounded = true;
            mainActivity.mMediaPlayerService = ((MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getServerInstance();
            MainActivity.this.mMediaPlayerService.setCallbacks(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };

    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        requestWindowFeature(1);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.wakeLock = ((PowerManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)))
                .newWakeLock(1, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");


        try {
            if (!isMyServiceRunning(MediaPlayerService.class)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
                intent.setAction("action.PLAY");
                bindService(intent, this.mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                startService(intent);
                return;
            }
            StartRadioPlayer_();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String sb = "onCreate: " + e.toString();
            Log.e(this.TAG, sb);
        }


    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (this.mBounded) {
            unbindService(this.mConnection);
            this.mBounded = false;
        }
    }

    public void callFromService() {
        StartRadioPlayer_();
    }


    public void onClickPlayPuse(View view) {
        MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService = this.mMediaPlayerService;
        if (mediaPlayerService == null || !mediaPlayerService.isPlaying()) {
            StartRadioPlayer();
            return;
        }
        StopRadioPlayer();
    }

    public void StartRadioPlayer_() {
        this.loadingImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.btnPlay_Puse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.btnPlay_Puse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        this.btnPlay_Puse.setTag("pause");
    }

    public void StartRadioPlayer() {
        MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService = this.mMediaPlayerService;
        if (mediaPlayerService != null) {
            mediaPlayerService.startMediaPlayer();
        }
    }

    public void StopRadioPlayer() {
        MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService = this.mMediaPlayerService;
        mediaPlayerService.stopMediaPlayer();

    }

    public boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = Objects.requireNonNull(cm).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> cls) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : ((ActivityManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)))
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (cls.getName().equals(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I expect Media player Stop without any error as below.

```
com.name.name.MainActivity.StopRadioPlayer (MainActivity.java:189)
com.name.name.MainActivity.onClickPlayPuse (MainActivity.java:162)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7341)
android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7307)
android.view.View.access$3200 (View.java:846)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:27789)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7097)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi Manoj. Sorry your linked answer is not simile to my quotation. i have describe in the quotation. i checked the null after check it i cant stop the service.